# How to get class declarations from create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

After creating a new react project using `npx create-react-app new` I'm getting functional js code in App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

//need to have a class instead of a function here:
function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What command do I need to create a none functional react project? If functional is better than none functional please explain why.

Comment: Which version of `create-react-app` are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have install `create-react-app` for this project, then it is come up with all the new features from react 16.8.6 (latest version of react). The latest react version come up with concept of [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). That is why we are getting functional component by default instead of class based component to increase the performance.

If you want class based component by default they you have to come up with older version of `create-react-app`. [Ref](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/)

Comment: I know how to write this myself. You are missing the point here, I need to create it from the command line. Without rewriting it.

Answer (score 3):

You can migrate `react-scripts` `v3.x` to **`v2.x`** like so:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --scripts-version react-scripts@2.1.7
```

Answer (score 1):

When a new react app is created using create-react-app, it pulls the template from here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts/template

Functional components are preferred than Class components (ES6 class) because, Functional components are usually stateless i.e. without any state and lifecycle methods - check this https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html. Their performance is better over class components which have state. Therefore, as a good practice one should always prefer as many stateless components (Functional) over stateful (Class), which is also done in react starter app i.e. create-react-app

Answer (score 1):

Use: `create-react-app <project> --scripts-version 2.1.7` to create a new react project that start with a class based App component rather than functional.

Comment: The question was how to create a project that uses class-based App component rather than functional, this gives the command to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are situations where a developer would prefer the class based design so the `--scripts-version` argument is good to know about.